# Prevent Malicious Data and Attacks in Form Input

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I am building a form in which user's will be able to put sensitive data like IBAN, BIC and personal data and also passport numbers, etc. Users will be able to edit those information and then update their data which are being saved in the database.

So far i have done:

1. Prevent SQL Injection by using prepared statements with ? as placeholder and bindValues for each input.
2. Escape all `$_GET` parameters that are being used in queries(also prepared) like this:

---

```
function escape($string = ''){
    return htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($string)), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

3. I have an hidden input : `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">` in which everytime the page is loaded i generate a unique hash like this:

---

```
public static function generate(){
    return $_SESSION['token_form'] = md5(uniqid());
}
```

and on form submit I check if the submitted token matches the session token so that I prevent CSRF Attacks.

All form inputs are texts except 3 date fields and all the fields I escape using the above function. I have no required fields so I don't need validation to check if empty. In the text field I expect text and in date I only expect date since a calendar pops up and the can only select date and not type.

Is there any other possible attack or thing I could prevent or take care in mind?

Comment: Your `escape` function is pointless and destructive. Get rid of it. You might also actually be looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: why is it pointless?

Comment: Because it 1) does not protect against SQL injection, 2) SQL injection is already being handled by parameterised statements, and 3) it doesn't even guarantee security against HTML injection on the output side (because who can guarantee that the value in the database *stays* HTML-encoded until it's being output?).

Comment: what HTML Injection are you saying? I do strip tags so i remove all the html and script tags that may someone wants to place

Comment: And again, doing so *on input* is not good enough. You need to HTML-escape when you put your values into HTML. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)